# CLIでイメージファイル(pngなど)中の文字列をマーキングしたい。

Tags: linux, 画像, png

linuxで、イメージファイル(pngなど)を開かずに、パラメータで指定した文字列を見つけて、パラメータで指定した色でマーキングして出力するようなことはできるでしょうか？
例えば：
$ convert　image.png  　文字列 　色　marked.png

Comment: 「開かずに」というのが「画面/ウインドウに表示せずに」という意味なら普通に可能な処理でしょう。実際に行いたいのはOCR(光学文字認識)処理で、画像の中の文字と思われる部分を抽出して何かの処理を行った結果を別のファイルとして出力することでしょうか？ そうした「やりたい事の詳細」をもう少し細分化して実際の画像や望ましい処理結果等も含めて追記してください。例えばこんな記事でしょうか？ [文字領域検出用のERFilterの使い方](https://qiita.com/TaroYamada/items/3334e879cf978740b542), [画像内のテキストを検出する](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr?hl=ja), [Remove background noise from image to make text more clear for OCR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33881175/9014308)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tesseract OCR](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract)コマンドを利用し、出力形式を`tsv`や`hocr`に指定することでテキストの領域を取得できます。
これと[imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php)のconvertを組み合わせることで任意のテキスト領域に枠線を描画可能です。

**コマンド例**

下記の例はtesseractの英語OCRで"character"という文字列を抽出し、青枠で囲います。

```
tesseract ocr.png ocr -l eng hocr
region=`awk 'match($0, /<span .+ ?title='\''bbox ([0-9 ]+) ([0-9 ]+) ([0-9 ]+) ([0-9 ]+)[^>]*>character<\/span>/, a){print "rectangle "a[1]","a[2]" "a[3]","a[4]}' ocr.hocr`
convert ocr.png -stroke blue -strokewidth 3 -fill none -draw "${region}" rect.png
```

- 1行目: tesseractでpngを読み込み、htmlで結果を抽出する(`hocr`ではなく`tsv`の方が再利用しやすい気がしますが、気づいたのはコマンドを組んだ後でした)
- 2行目: 上記のhtmlから正規表現で本文が"character"となっているspanタグ(下記サンプル)の領域を取得、整形する

  - `<span class="ocrx_word" id="word_1_6" title="bbox 25 185 315 236; x_wconf 96">character</span>`
- 3行目: convertで`-stroke blue -strokewidth 3`の枠線を描画する

**事前準備**

```
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr libtesseract-dev tesseract-ocr-eng
sudo apt install graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
```

**成果物**

[image: 成果物]

**参考資料**

[tesseractコマンドの使い方（Tesseract OCR 4.x）](https://blog.machine-powers.net/2018/08/02/learning-tesseract-command-utility/#%E5%87%BA%E5%8A%9B%E5%BD%A2%E5%BC%8F)
[OCRを使用してLinuxコマンドラインで画像をテキストに変換する](https://technoglitz.com/japan/ocr%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6linux%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%81%A7%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E3%82%92%E3%83%86%E3%82%AD%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%AB/)